# How to find a HTML tag with runat=server into a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I'm generating a table using a `Repeater` and I need to set a `<td>` as `runat=server` to set visibility for it.

I'm trying to find it into `ItemDataBound` event using `FindControl` method, but it doesn't work. 
Hot can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some relevant code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, you should write like this:

```
Visible=<%= SetVisiblity() %>
```

where SetVisiblity is a public function

Comment: Where SetVisibility returns a boolean. Protected should be enough

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  First, create a method called to catch the repeater's OnDataItemBound event.

```
protected void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
   // Use FindControl, but start from the context of the RepeaterItem.
   //
   HtmlTableCell cell = e.item.FindControl("CellID") as HtmlTableCell;

   if ( cell != null )
   {
      // Do what you gotta do.
   }
}
```

You can explicitly wire the event up on the repeater markup.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
</asp:Repeater>
```